# ThinkPad X121E BIOS: UEFI/Legacy Ubuntu Installation doen't start

Tags: ubuntu, thinkpad

I got a ThinkPad X121E which refuses to install Ubuntu Linux (neither 32 nor 64 Bit). Windows7 64 Bit is no problem though.

Here the details:

- Installation works perfectly (I do partitions manually and encrypt the `/home` drive)
- After restarting, Ubuntu doesn't boot, but the ThinkPad BIOS does boot twice and beeps when leaving the pre-boot window. After a short moment the message

  > Operating System not found

  is displayed, or depending on wether the BIOS settings are UEFI-only/Legacy-only the LAN Boot routine tries before that. If you now reboot it again, it won't boot twice but still beeps when leaving the pre-boot window.

Hope that were the kind of information you actually needed to help.

A few links which seemed kind of promising:

- ["No operating System found"](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/no-operating-system-found/3/) (German) was really interesting as it is stated that GRUB wont work with GPT (and `fdisk` says that GPT is used), but sadly cuts off too early to the luck of the OP with his 32Bit system (that failed on me though).
- [This UbuntuForums.org thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1814868) is interesting but cuts off on a too early stage as well.

Comment: You should.  "it didn't start" is not [an account of what specific messages, sounds, and lights the computer presented to you](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).

Comment: well, the OS doesn't start an as there is no other OS installed the message "no Operating System found" is displayed

Comment: Just repeating "it doesn't start" doesn't help, either.  Think!  _We're not clairvoyant; we need to be told what the symptoms are_.  _Exact_ error messages are important.  Was it "no operating system found" or "operating system not found", for example?  The difference is important.  Edit your question and put all of the details in.

Comment: Isn't it a problem related with the fact that you have already 3 principal partitions (maximun allowed is 4)? In x121e Windows 7 comes with 3 principal partitions (drivers, recover and OS). I can't have a successful instalation exactly because with the Mint partition it makes 4 and then there is no possibility to have a swap partition. Still didn't find a solution for a dual boot win-linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Ubuntu (at the moment just Ubuntu, no dual boot tested), just let the installation routine do its work, don't set your own partitions as this somehow messes things up!

That worked for me, even with a 64Bit OS.

Comment: Obviously this is only a solution if you don't need dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Crescent Nebula Blog](http://cnebula.blogspot.com/2012/03/thinkpad-x121e-running-64-bit-ubuntu.html)

> - To repair a defect MBR ("No operating system", or "Grub error, invalid arch independent ELF magic") I booted Partion Magic and did in
>     console: "ms-sys -7 /dev/sdXXX" where sdXXX is a placeholder. In my
>     special case it is just "sdb". the correct device id I got from
>     gparted.
> - Setup BIOS:  Menu "Startup"
>
>   - UEFI/Legacy Boot: both  (UEFI *and* Legacy)
>   - UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority: "Legacy first" (important!)
>   - You have to setup BIOS before (!) installation.   Otherwise you encounter "Grub error, invalid arch independent ELF magic" or "No
>       operating system"
> - Setup BIOS: Menu "USB"
>
>   - USB UEFI BIOS Support may be "Enabled".

Comment: The link to the blog seems dead. I have a similar problem to the OP, why is it important to have Legacy first? Doesn't modern GRUB use UEFI? Or is it something that's changed since the OP in 2011?